# Is the Cairo airport safe at night?

Tags: airports, security, cairo, cai

Tomorrow I will take a flight from Rome Fiumicino to Cairo Airoport that leaves at 10.35 PM and arrives at 2.35 AM in Cairo, Terminal 1A.
Someone will send a taxi to catch me at the airport, but I have some doubts. Therefore I'd like to know if I could stay inside the airport till morning and then take a taxi.

Is Cairo airport safe? Does it close during the night?

Would I have some security problems in getting outside the airport alone to look for a taxi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cairo airport, along with every site in Egypt remotely connected to tourism, has *ridiculous* amounts of security, so you are in absolutely no physical danger.  If you wait until morning, all that's going to happen is that you'll be stuck in a traffic jam on your way to the city!

What's more, since the revolution, Cairo's rather notorious unmetered taxis are no longer allowed at the airport.  If you ignore touts, pick a cab off the rank and insist on the meter, **you should be perfectly fine**.  (Well, aside from the abysmal standards of Egyptian driving, but that's another story.  I still remember driving to the airport one night past the wreck of a BMW that had *literally* wrapped itself around a lamppost.)

All that said, if somebody is arranging a transfer for you, it's presumably not going to be an ordinary taxi, but somebody known to whoever is sending them.  So get them to stand outside Customs holding a placard with your name on it, and get their phone number as a backup in case you can't find them.

(Mild disclaimer: I haven't been back to Cairo since they opened the new terminal, but it wasn't a particularly hard airport to deal with even before.)

Comment: Very useful answer! Thank you very much! I will follow your advice and I will tell them to go just outside the customs.
Best regards!
Marco